# Make zoom use system proxy

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, proxy, zoom.app

I'm in China, and Zoom on my Mac often gets stuck because of unstable connection to Zoom server. I have a http(s) proxy that works great (I get 0% packet loss with this proxy, and 30%-40% otherwise). However, Zoom usually ignores the proxy.

Can I force Zoom to use the http(s) proxy configured in "Network Preferences" panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/). Add the https proxy in "proxy", and add rule for Zoom.us to use "https proxy".